# python is showing a list of things to install on typing python -v in windows

Tags: python, installation

I have installed python 3.9.1 on my windows device and python is installed successfully on it, but pip is not working and also python is not showing the version on running command "python -v" instead, it is showing a list flies and to import. I had also to set the path but still, the same problem is arising. A screenshot of the issue is attached.

Comment: That's not a list of things to install. It's verbose import logging - it's dumping a bunch of information about `import`s. Also, you didn't attach that screenshot (and this kind of stuff should be posted as code-formatted text, not screenshots).

Answer (score 1):

It's `python -V` (V in uppercase)

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you're using a lower case "v".
 Try: `python -V` or `python --version`
 If you need to print this info inside of python, try:

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.python_version()
```

Or

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
```